# Iterating over 2d arrays contained in 3d array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, iteration, vectorization

I have seen a lot of questions asking for a faster way to iterate over each element of a 2d array, but I haven't found a good method to iterate over a 3d array in order to apply a function on each 2d array. For example:

```
from scipy.fftpack import dct
X = np.arange(10000, dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,4,4)
np.array(map(dct, X))
```

Here I'm going through each 2d array contained in a 3d array of dimensions `(625,4,4)` and applying a DCT (discrete cosine transform) to each `4X4` array. I was wondering if there is a more suitable method to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Numpy Functions:**

Well in this case, since `dct` is a `numpy` function, it has the functionality built-in to apply it over a particular axis. Nearly all numpy functions operate on complete arrays or can be told to operate on a particular axis (row or column).

So just by leveraging the `axis` parameter for `dct` function:

```
dct( X, axis=2)
```

you will get an equivalent result:

```
>>> ( dct(X, axis=2) == np.array(map(dct, X)) ).all()
True
```

which is also >35 times faster than using the `map` function in our case of `(625,4,4)` matrix:

```
%timeit dct(X, axis=2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 157 µs per loop

%timeit np.array(map(dct, X))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.76 ms per loop
```

**General Python Functions:**

In other cases, you can `vectorize` a python function using either [np.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) or [np.frompyfunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) functions. For instance if you have a demo function that performs a scalar operation:

```
def foo(x): # gives an error if passed in an array
    return x**2

>>> X = np.arange(8, dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2,2)
>>> foo_arr = np.vectorize( foo)
>>> foo_arr(X)
array([[[  0.,   1.],
        [  4.,   9.]],

       [[ 16.,  25.],
        [ 36.,  49.]]])
```

Discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079061/function-application-over-numpys-matrix-row-column) might also be helpful for you. As they say, vectorizing your non-numpy function doesn't actually make it any faster though.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that dct's axis parameter could be used in this situation. Regarding your general solution,what you described in last part of your answer is precisely why I was wondering about an alternative to np.vectorize.