# Better way to map a function (cosine similarity) to each row in scipy.csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy

Suppose I have a sparse matrix of document collection, where each row is a vector representing a document (generated by scikit-learn's tfidf_transformer for example).

```
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(posting)
```

Now I have a query coming in,

```
query = transformer.transform(vectorizer.transform(['I am a sample query']))
```

So I want to compare this query, to each of the document (each row) of the matrix using scipy.spatial.distance.cosine (cosine similarity). So I do a map as follows

```
result = map(lambda document: cosine(document.toarray(), query[0].toarray()), tfidf_matrix)
```

it could be done with a loop as well

```
result = []
for row in tfidf_matrix:
    result = result + [cosine(row.toarray(), query[0].toarray())]
```

However, it is slow (I threw in a gevent.threadpool.map to it out of frustration with same result). I am pretty sure this is not the right way of doing this (mapping a function to each row of a sparse matrix), but I can't seem to find the proper way of doing this.

So the question is, what is the proper way to map a function to each row in the sparse matrix (scipy.csr_matrix)?

Comment: just a note, for this particular case (cosine similarity), this is the best way to do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/18914884/5742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed was that you're running `query[0].toarray()` every time you go through the `for` loop (or on every iteration of the `map()` call). Is that value ever going to change in between rows? Because if it isn't, you can save some time by calculating it just one, outside the `for` loop:

```
result = []
query_array = query[0].toarray()
for row in tfidf_matrix:
    result = result + [cosine(row.toarray(), query_array)]
```

Also, don't do `result = result + [another_list_element]`; that's much slower than `result.append(another_list_element)`. In this case, you should be doing:

```
result = []
query_array = query[0].toarray()
for row in tfidf_matrix:
    result.append(cosine(row.toarray(), query_array))
```

Or with `map`, that would be:

```
query_array = query[0].toarray()
result = map(lambda document: cosine(document.toarray(), query_array), tfidf_matrix)
```

There may be other speedups possible as well, but try this one and see if it helps.

**EDIT:** Also, have you seen [Function application over numpy's matrix row/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079061/function-application-over-numpys-matrix-row-column)? It looks like the `vectorize` function may be what you want. I can't give you more details since I'm not really familiar with numpy and scipy myself, but that looks like a good starting point for your reading.

Comment: the reason I needed toarray() is because cosine(u, v) would throw "ValueError: dimension mismatch" (though both should be in the same dimension since both are result returned by the tfidf_transformer).

Comment: But do you need to run `toarray()` every time through the loop, or will calculating it once outside the loop be enough?

Comment: yea, i could do query[0].toarray() outside the loop (: thanks for reminding. I am just curious whether there's a easier (and possibly faster) way to do this